# Correct text message time after boot up

Tags: sms, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s

Every time I have my phone *turned off* or in *flight mode*, after I turn it on again, the message sent to me while the phone was down appears to be received at the moment the phone finished booting up.

Is there any setting / work around that could display the time when the text message was sent / supposed to be received?

Comment: This might depend on your network, AFAIK the sent time is only available if the network provides it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some carriers do attach the sent time with the SMS. I'm not sure if it depends on the sender's or receiver's carrier. And some Android SMS apps let you choose that instead of local phone time. The SMS app in CyanogenMod 7 does for one, but check out HandCent, ChompSMS and Go SMS for alternative messaging apps.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's an [application issue](http://community.windmobile.ca/windmobile/topics/correct_text_message_time_after_boot_up#reply_6407824):

> The SMS packet itself that is sent from the SMSC to your phone, has a
>   field called SCTS, Service Center Time Stamp, which indicates the time
>   that the message was received by the SMSC.
>
> Unfortunately, the SMS application on Android seems to ignore this
>   timestamp and instead uses and stores the current system time (in ms
>   since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).